# Access data from a drive without mounting

Tags: linux, mount, hard-drive

Recently my hard drive on my dedicated server crashed and the hosting company had to replace the drive. however I had a backup hard drive that was taking daily backups.

Now I have a new drive and a fresh OS installed. the backup hard drive is attached to the server but I am not sure how to access the drive and restore the backup files.

would mounting the drive remove all the current data on it? if yes then whats the best way to restore the data from the hard drive? (also I dont have physical access to the drive)

Comment: off topic on stackoverflow.. anyway, *mounting* a harddisk does not remove any data,  *formatting* does

Comment: Thank you so much. Im sorry if it was offtopic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. you need to know what was filesystem used on backup drive
   (mounting will not erase any files *unless* you use wrong filetype declaration)
2. you need to know the name of the backup device (for example: `/dev/sdaX`)
3. now as a root on your fresh system create a mountpoint (a directory) - usually you should put it in `/mnt`, for example `/mnt/backup`
4. do mount -t [filesystem on backup drive] [backup device] [mountpoint]
   for example:

   `mount -t ext4 /dev/sda5 /mnt/backup`
5. if everything is fine all your backup is available in /mnt/backup and you can do whatever you want with it

See:
http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount
http://www.linfo.org/mount_point.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Fdisk -l listed the partition as /dev/sdb1 but when I tried to mount sdb1 I got an error saying "special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist". I tried going to /dev directory I only found /dev/sdb.

Comment: /dev/sdb is a representation of a whole physical disk, /dev/sdb1 would be first partition on this disk. I've read about that error, but never actually got one, it was some problem with device mapper iirc tho. Ask on http://serverfault.com :)